# Opção de cancelar o voto para reabrir

Tags: novo-recurso

[Este tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22400/javascript-deixou-de-funcionar) estava em suspenso. Eu li mais uma vez a pergunta e os comentários e pensei na possibilidade de reabertura, mas depois de pensar mais um pouco, não faz sentido porque ainda não está claro o problema dele – falta detalhes. Nos comentários, aliás, estamos tentando decifrar o enigma. Portanto, mudei a minha ideia sobre a reabertura e gostaria de retirar o meu voto: como faço?

Se não há essa possibilidade ainda, não é algo a se pensar?

Não é possível retirar o voto de reabertura assim como dá para retirar o de encerramento, se clicar em reabrir para tentar retirar o voto aparece a seguinte janela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se clicar em OK daí aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se clicar em Cancela não acontece nada.

Comment: Engraçado, tem um post desse no MetaSE [Cancel a reopen request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147420/229289) que foi fechado como duplicado de [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/229289). Talvez por ser um post velho foram tomadas ações nesse meio tempo que deixou o fechamento incoerente, já que é possível cancelar o voto de fechamento porém não o de reabertura.